# Is it possible to use the Lego EV3 simulink library without wi-fi connectivity?

Tags: matlab, simulink, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

The setup instructions say that some kind of network connectivity is required, but I don't understand why they're mandatory when the mindstorm programmer doesn't require it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/legomindstormsev3io/index.html) Matlab supports both Bluetooth and USB.

To understand this, you need to understand the [layers of communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) that are being used. At the application level of the official LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 software, it appears that USB, Bluetooth and Wi-Fi all work the same. At lower layers, however, they are quite different.

Wi-Fi provides a "network" connection. Technically, this is [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) over [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) (layers 3 and 4 in the first link). This is also the level where Simulink is most likely interfacing.

USB, on the other hand, is implemented as an [HID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) device. And Bluetooth is implemented using [RFCOMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_protocols#RFCOMM).

So, to make them all work, Simulink would have to have three very different communication implementations. Also, of the three types of connections, Wi-Fi provides the most bandwidth/throughput, so the decision to only implement this could also have to do with how much data is being passed back and forth.

Comment: So is the answer to that no? I understand why it would be more difficult one way, but that doesn't necessarily mean that they didn't.